# How would I set up a method to update passed properties of JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype

I'm looking to create a method for an object to update only the properties that are passed.

for example

```
function Car () {
  this.color = 'yellow'
  this.brand = 'bmw'
  this.key = 0

  this.update = function (o) {
    this.key++
    // maybe Object.assign(this, o) somehow ??
  }
}
```

If I do `Car.update({color:'red'})` I want to update the object but not overwrite the brand.  I want to use something like `Object.assign(this, o)` but not sure how to assign it.  Do I need to create a prototype? `Car.prototype.update = ?`

Comment: So what went wrong with `Object.assign`? It *will* update `this` if you pass that as first argument. No need to assign anything more.

Comment: but i would have to assign it to something right?  like this = Object.assign(this, o)  but that's a no-go

Comment: You need to create a `new Car()` first

Comment: @trincot Ah, i see.  looking at the docs, i didn't realize it copies to the first parameter which is the target.  I thought it had to return something which you would then save to a var.  convert that to an answer.  :)

Comment: OK, I have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` mutates the first argument, so there is no need to assign the result of `Object.assign()` to something.

```
Object.assign(this, o);
```

...will work fine.

```js
function Car () {
  this.color = 'yellow'
  this.brand = 'bmw'
  this.key = 0

  this.update = function (o) {
    this.key++
    Object.assign(this, o);
  }
}

var car = new Car();
car.update({color: 'red'});
console.log(car);
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea you suggested in your OP works fine.

```js
function Car () {
  this.color = 'yellow';
  this.brand = 'bmw';
  this.key = 0;

  this.update = function (o) {
 Object.assign(this, o);
  }
}

a = new Car();
a.update({color: "red"});
console.log(a.color + " - " + a.brand + " - " + a.key);
// returns "red - bmw - 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {
color : 'red'
};

const obj2 = Object.assign({color: 'blue', d: 5}, object1);
console.log(obj2.color); // red
```

Object.assign() method -> copy the values of all enumerable own properties.
Finally It will return the target object

Comment: I just wanted it to be in a method, to keep it clean and so i can tie other functionality to it whenever there is an update, i updated my question to show what else I would like to tie in.  to give a better idea of what i'm trying to accomplish